# What is the best way to design a status check/heartbeat for a RESTful API?

Tags: rest, api-design

At work I have been asked to provide a simple status check for an API which serves two different URL resources.

The resources use a different set of databases and third party APIs.

There is no standard for this kind of status check within our company and I am trying to decide what the best approach is.

1. Have one HTTP status check resource which ensures all databases and third parties are contactable and report which API resources do not work based on any component being irresponsive.
2. Have different status checks for each of the API resources.

What would be the cleanest way to do this so it is extensible in the long run?

Comment: If the goal is a RESTful API, I would ask the question: *does it make sense to handle these as different resources?* If it does, go with option 2.

Answer (score 1):

A mix of both.

Have each api resource checked by its own component. The component class can be the same for more than one resources, as long as they listen and respond in the same manner.

Next, have one observer which uses components as standard plugs so you can add, delete, activate/deactivate etc. components in it. The observer should have no knowledge about resources or their APIs, it would just use components' interface to get info.